# Why is this set of F rotating in this locus

Tags: webgl, webgl2

In this code , I am not able to understand why the rotation is not in circular locus. This may be basic logic behind this but i can't understand why this so random locus.

I am rotating camera in orbital motion but it is not following it.

In my knowledge, i created a orbital motion camera and inverse of that is view matrix. So, view matrix will transform the world space for this result.Is there any fault in my thinking process ?

```js
"use strict";

const vertexShader = `#version 300 es

    in vec4 a_position;
    in vec4 a_color;

    out vec4 v_color;

    uniform mat4 u_matrix;

    void main(){
        gl_Position = u_matrix*a_position;
        v_color = a_color;
    }
`;


const fragShader = `#version 300 es

    precision highp float;

        in vec4 v_color;
        out vec4 frag_color;

        void main(){
            frag_color = v_color;
        }
`;

var cameraAngleDegree = 0;
var  cameraAngle = 0;
const radius = 100;
var increment = 1;
var numFs = 5;
function main() {

    var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
    if (!gl) {
        return;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        init(gl);
    });
}

function init(gl) {


    const program = webglUtils.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vertexShader, fragShader]);

    const apositionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
    const acolorLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_color');
    const umatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_matrix');

    let vao = gl.createVertexArray();
    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

    let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    setGeometry(gl);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(apositionLoc);

    let size = 3;
    let type = gl.FLOAT;
    let normalize = false;
    let stride = 0;
    let offset = 0;
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(apositionLoc, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    let colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    setColor(gl);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(acolorLoc);

    size = 3;
    type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
    normalize = true;
    stride = 0;
    offset = 0;
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(acolorLoc, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    let fov = degreeToRadian(60);
    cameraAngle = degreeToRadian(cameraAngleDegree);

    function degreeToRadian(deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    function radToDegree(rad) {
        return rad * (180) / Math.PI;
    }

    drawScene();

    // webglLessonsUI.setupSlider("#cameraAngle", { value: radToDegree(cameraAngle), slide: updateCameraAngle, min: -360, max: 360 });

    // function updateCameraAngle(event, ui) {
    //     cameraAngle = degreeToRadian(ui.value);
    //     drawScene();
    // }


    function drawScene() {

        webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

        gl.useProgram(program);

        let aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;

        let projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, 1, 1000);

        const fPosition = [radius, 0, 0];

        cameraAngleDegree += increment;

        cameraAngle =degreeToRadian(cameraAngleDegree);
        
        let camera = m4.yRotation(cameraAngle);
        camera = m4.translate(camera, 0, 100, 300);

        let cameraPosition = [camera[12], camera[13], camera[14]];

        // let up = [0, 1, 0];

        // camera = m4.lookAt(cameraPosition, fPosition, up);

        let viewMatrix = m4.inverse(camera);

        let viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, viewMatrix);

        for (var ii = 0; ii < numFs; ++ii) {
            var angle = ii * Math.PI * 2 / numFs;

            var x = Math.cos(angle) * radius;
            var z = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
            var matrix = m4.translate(viewProjection, x, 0, z);

            // Set the matrix.
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(umatrixLoc, false, matrix);

            // Draw the geometry.
            var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
            var offset = 0;
            var count = 16 * 6;
            gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
        }
        //     gl.uniformMatrix4fv(umatrixLoc, false, viewProjection);

        //     var primitives = gl.TRIANGLES;
        //     var count = 16 * 6;
        //     var offset = 0;
        //     gl.drawArrays(primitives, offset, count);

        // }

        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            init(gl)
        });

    }
}

function setGeometry(gl) {

    let positions = new Float32Array([

        0, 0, 0,
        0, 150, 0,
        30, 0, 0,
        0, 150, 0,
        30, 150, 0,
        30, 0, 0,

        // top rung front
        30, 0, 0,
        30, 30, 0,
        100, 0, 0,
        30, 30, 0,
        100, 30, 0,
        100, 0, 0,

        // middle rung front
        30, 60, 0,
        30, 90, 0,
        67, 60, 0,
        30, 90, 0,
        67, 90, 0,
        67, 60, 0,

        // left column back
        0, 0, 30,
        30, 0, 30,
        0, 150, 30,
        0, 150, 30,
        30, 0, 30,
        30, 150, 30,

        // top rung back
        30, 0, 30,
        100, 0, 30,
        30, 30, 30,
        30, 30, 30,
        100, 0, 30,
        100, 30, 30,

        // middle rung back
        30, 60, 30,
        67, 60, 30,
        30, 90, 30,
        30, 90, 30,
        67, 60, 30,
        67, 90, 30,

        // top
        0, 0, 0,
        100, 0, 0,
        100, 0, 30,
        0, 0, 0,
        100, 0, 30,
        0, 0, 30,

        // top rung right
        100, 0, 0,
        100, 30, 0,
        100, 30, 30,
        100, 0, 0,
        100, 30, 30,
        100, 0, 30,

        // under top rung
        30, 30, 0,
        30, 30, 30,
        100, 30, 30,
        30, 30, 0,
        100, 30, 30,
        100, 30, 0,

        // between top rung and middle
        30, 30, 0,
        30, 60, 30,
        30, 30, 30,
        30, 30, 0,
        30, 60, 0,
        30, 60, 30,

        // top of middle rung
        30, 60, 0,
        67, 60, 30,
        30, 60, 30,
        30, 60, 0,
        67, 60, 0,
        67, 60, 30,

        // right of middle rung
        67, 60, 0,
        67, 90, 30,
        67, 60, 30,
        67, 60, 0,
        67, 90, 0,
        67, 90, 30,

        // bottom of middle rung.
        30, 90, 0,
        30, 90, 30,
        67, 90, 30,
        30, 90, 0,
        67, 90, 30,
        67, 90, 0,

        // right of bottom
        30, 90, 0,
        30, 150, 30,
        30, 90, 30,
        30, 90, 0,
        30, 150, 0,
        30, 150, 30,

        // bottom
        0, 150, 0,
        0, 150, 30,
        30, 150, 30,
        0, 150, 0,
        30, 150, 30,
        30, 150, 0,

        // left side
        0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 30,
        0, 150, 30,
        0, 0, 0,
        0, 150, 30,
        0, 150, 0,

    ]);

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
}

function setColor(gl) {
    gl.bufferData(
        gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        new Uint8Array([
            // left column front
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,

            // top rung front
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,

            // middle rung front
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,
            200, 70, 120,

            // left column back
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,

            // top rung back
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,

            // middle rung back
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,
            80, 70, 200,

            // top
            70, 200, 210,
            70, 200, 210,
            70, 200, 210,
            70, 200, 210,
            70, 200, 210,
            70, 200, 210,

            // top rung right
            200, 200, 70,
            200, 200, 70,
            200, 200, 70,
            200, 200, 70,
            200, 200, 70,
            200, 200, 70,

            // under top rung
            210, 100, 70,
            210, 100, 70,
            210, 100, 70,
            210, 100, 70,
            210, 100, 70,
            210, 100, 70,

            // between top rung and middle
            210, 160, 70,
            210, 160, 70,
            210, 160, 70,
            210, 160, 70,
            210, 160, 70,
            210, 160, 70,

            // top of middle rung
            70, 180, 210,
            70, 180, 210,
            70, 180, 210,
            70, 180, 210,
            70, 180, 210,
            70, 180, 210,

            // right of middle rung
            100, 70, 210,
            100, 70, 210,
            100, 70, 210,
            100, 70, 210,
            100, 70, 210,
            100, 70, 210,

            // bottom of middle rung.
            76, 210, 100,
            76, 210, 100,
            76, 210, 100,
            76, 210, 100,
            76, 210, 100,
            76, 210, 100,

            // right of bottom
            140, 210, 80,
            140, 210, 80,
            140, 210, 80,
            140, 210, 80,
            140, 210, 80,
            140, 210, 80,

            // bottom
            90, 130, 110,
            90, 130, 110,
            90, 130, 110,
            90, 130, 110,
            90, 130, 110,
            90, 130, 110,

            // left side
            160, 160, 220,
            160, 160, 220,
            160, 160, 220,
            160, 160, 220,
            160, 160, 220,
            160, 160, 220,
        ]),
        gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

main();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Traingle Webgl 2</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    @import url("https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-tutorials.css");

    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    button {
        position: absolute;
    }

    canvas {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div id="uiContainer">
        <div id="ui">
            <div id="cameraAngle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--
for most samples webgl-utils only provides shader compiling/linking and
canvas resizing because why clutter the examples with code that's the same in every sample.
See https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html
and https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html
for webgl-utils, m3, m4, and webgl-lessons-ui.
-->
    <script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-lessons-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/m4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://greggman.github.io/webgl-helpers/webgl-gl-error-check.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lookat.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/camera.js"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, the problem you see is it looks like the camera is getting closer to and further from the Fs

The issue is the vertex data for the Fs are built so the top left front corner is at 0,0,0, from that they go +X 100 units (so 100 units wide), +Y 150 units (so 100 units tall), and +Z 30 units so 30 units deep

So then, when you draw them around a 100 unit circle their origin is the part you are positioning and you get this

[image]

The image is top down so the Fs are just a rectangle. The green circle is the local origin of each F, its local 0,0,0. The other vertices of the F are relative to that local origin so they are closer to the outer circle (the orbit of the camera) on one side and further on the other

You can fix it by moving the Fs -50 in X and -15 in Z. In other words

```
            var angle = ii * Math.PI * 2 / numFs;

            var x = Math.cos(angle) * radius - 50;
            var z = Math.sin(angle) * radius - 15;
```

Which gives you this situation

[image]

The local origin of each F is no longer on the circle.

You could also fix it by centering the F vertex data, go through all the vertices and subtract 50 from X and 15 from Z. That would give you this situation

[image]

Now the origin of each F is centered and it's local origin is on the circle.

Yet another way to fix it would be to compute the extents of the group of Fs, compute the center of the extents, move the center of the camera orbit there which would be this situation

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am happy that i asked this question. Now i have clear and better idea of  local vertices. Thanks a lot. I am curious to ask one thing, after doing all this, what i have learnt from your sites is that there is actually no camera. We are actually moving scene objects that would create effect relative to the effect that we wanted from camera.That's why we compute inverse of the camera matrix so that negation of that on scene can be rendered which bring same transformation as camera had brought if camera had moved. Am i right ? or i am carrying some logical fallacy.

Comment: You're not wrong. It depends on your P.O.V.  In general, yes, the math moves everything relative to the camera, the camera itself doesn't move. But when I'm actually doing 3D wI think in terms of moving the camera and ignore the fact that in the implementation of the math the camera is not moving and instead everything is is being made relative to it.

Comment: Thanks alot for your perfect answers.